# Est-ce que « Merci » tout seul, sans autres indices de refus, peut servir pour refuser une offre ?

Tags: sens

(Question in the "Question Heading" restated in English):

> When used all alone with no other indications of refusal, can “Merci”
>   be used to refuse an offer?

J’ai un ami Normand, un peu près l’âge de mon père, qui à l’époque avait toujours le droit de faire bouillir son propre calvados et une fois chez lui il me proposait d’en boire une goutte.  Je lui ai répondu simplement « Merci », en préparant ma bouche pour ce vrai de vrai délice.

Mais malheureusement je restais au sec pendant qu’il me traite de « faux-américain » car, dans ses propres mots :

« En ’44 parmi tous les GIs qui sont passés par ici, et y’en avait un paquet je t’assure, PAS UN SEUL disait *NON* à notre calva. Pour qui tu te prends ? ».

« Mais je n’ai pas dit *Non*, mon cher ami » -- j’ai insisté, pas mal confus -- «  Au contraire, je vous avais dit *Merci* à votre proposition hyper-sympa ».

Alors avec ça mon ami Normand a vite compris notre malentendu et j’ai fini par avoir ma goutte précieuse pendant qu’il m’explique, très poliment cette fois-ci, que chez lui:

> « Merci » tout seul égale un refus d’une offre.

Depuis ce temps-là, je fais gaffe et je ne dis jamais « Merci » sans ajouter soit « non » ou soit « oui » (surtout « oui » quand il s’agit du calva !), mais je me demande toujours :

> Est-ce que le propos de mon ami Normand (que « Merci = un refus d’une
>   offre ») est valable partout en France/au monde francophone et pour toutes les générations
>   des Français/Francophones ou est-ce que son propos est plutôt limité à la Normandie
>   et/ou aux gens d’un certain âge ?

Pour les recherches que j’ai déjà faites, dans mon dictionnaire personnel « Le Robert-Micro » je trouve :

« **Merci**…..3 •  Formule de politesse accompagnant un refus. Non, merci ».

Et sur Larousse online, je trouve :

« [**Merci**](http://www.larousse.com/en/dictionaries/french/merci/50583?q=merci#50471)…..3 •  Terme de politesse accompagnant un refus : Merci, non merci, je n'ai plus faim. »

Les deux dictionnaires  parlent de « … **accompagnant** un refus » qui, pour moi, ne veut pas dire « … exprimant, tout seul, un refus »,

mais les exemples donnés par Larousse (Merci, non merci, je n'ai plus faim) me confondent car je ne sais pas s’il faut les comprendre comme :

deux exemples qui sont clairement les refus (1-Merci, je n'ai plus faim et 2-Non merci, je n'ai plus faim)

ou plutôt comme :

trois exemples indépendants (1-Merci ; 2-non merci ; et 3- je n'ai plus faim), parmi eux se trouve « Merci » tout seul en tête, qui me semble en conflit avec l’idée de « accompagnant » (sans parlant du fait que « 3- je n'ai plus faim », vu comme un exemple indépendant, n’inclut  ni « merci » ni « non merci » dedans).

(Si ma question a été déjà demandé ici et donc un duplicata, je suis désolé mais je ne l’ai pas trouvée parmi les questions concernant « Merci ».)

Plus rien à dire sauf, bien sûr,  un grand merci d’avance !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

J'ai souvent observé ce même malentendu avec un collègue d'origine russe, par exemple lors de dialogues avec des serveurs.

À moins d'être accompagné d'une gestuelle indiquant clairement l'acquiescement, je n'ai jamais rencontré en France de situation où « **Merci** » employé seul et à la suite d'une question n'était pas compris comme un refus par les personnes dont le français est la langue maternelle. Ce n'est qu'une ellipse pour « **Non merci** ».

On n'utilise d'ailleurs que très rarement l'expression « **Oui merci** » car le remerciement arrive trop tôt. L'expression consacrée est « **Oui, s'il vous plait** » ou « **Oui, s'il te plait** ». Ici aussi, la formule peut être réduite à « **S'il vous plait** ».

Attention, cette ellipse de « **Non merci** » en « **Merci** » n'est pas forcément présente dans d'autres régions francophones que la France, et en particulier en Belgique ou « Merci » est plus associé à une acceptation.

Comment: Your phrase:«On ... "Oui merci" CAR LE REMERCIEMENT ARRIVE TROP TOT» confuses me. Does it mean that, to avoid being “trop tôt,” «un remerciement»(by saying “Merci” alone) shouldn't occur until AFTER an appreciated ACTION has been COMPLETED? If so could “Merci” alone be seen as ending the exchange by implying: «Merci (pour votre action appréciée), je suis comblé pour l’instant»? If these ideas make sense, it helps me "get" «'Merci' seul, comme refus d’une offer»,i.e., «Merci (pour votre action appréciée[=de m’avoir fait l’offre]), je suis comblé pour l’instant», thus ending the exchange.

Comment: I understand your confusion but the fact is you generally shouldn't thank before the fact, that would look like an order (eg: "*Merci de fermer la porte en sortant*"). If you want to thank for the offer, you would state it clearly like: "*Merci de me le proposer, j'en boirais bien une goutte !*"

Comment: C'est faux, il existe des différences... En belgique dire "merci" veut dire oui, alors qu'en France non. "Voulez-vous plus de bière ? - Merci !" ==> en Belgique : "c'est reparti pour un litre !", et en France : "non merci j'ai trop bu...".

Comment: @Shautieh Possible, je vérifierais lors de mon prochain séjour outre-Quiévrain... Ce qui est sûr, c'est que « S'il vous plait » y est employé différemment.

Comment: Je confirme les dires de Shautieh, quand j'accepte une proposition, je dis simplement "merci". J'essaie cependant de lever toute ambiguité en utilisant "volontiers" et "non merci" car effectivement en fonction des personnes le "merci" est interprété différemment.

Comment: @LaurentS. Alstublieft ;-) Je met à jour ma réponse.

Comment: In Québec, you almost never encounter it alone as an answer to a proposition. You will have "Oui, merci", "Oui, s'il vous plait" or "Non, merci".  You will only have "Merci" alone after the fact to mean "Thank you".

Answer (score 4):

Je ne sais pas si c'est mon interprétation suisse de la question, ou si certaines nuances existent.

En effet, il me semble que si on me dit: *«Veux-tu encore un peu de café ?»* et que ma réponse est *«Merci !»*, elle va signifier *«Non merci !»*.
Alors que si l'on est plus affirmatif avec *«Je te verse un peu de café ?*» et que ma réponse est *«Merci !»*, elle va signifier *«Oui, merci !»*.
Tout est certainement aussi dans le ton de la réponse...

Comment: Ton et gestuelle. J'accompagne généralement un « Merci » (pour non) d'un geste de la main et un « s'il vous plaît » (pour oui/volontiers) d'un acquièscement de la tête.

Comment: @Chop exactement ! J'ajouterais que "merci" peut aussi s'accompagner d'un acquiescement de la tête pour oui et d'un hochement latéral pour non (parfois même hochement + signe de la main). Dans tous les cas, le mot seul est ambigu et peut être interprété différemment selon les personnes/régions

Answer (score 2):

J’employais souvent « merci » sans « non » pour refuser une proposition ou, à l’inverse, « s’il-vous-plaît/s’il-te-plaît » sans « oui » pour en accepter une<sup>1</sup>.

Cependant, il m’est arrivé d’être incompris. J’essaie désormais d’utiliser systématiquement « oui » ou « non » dans mes réponses.

---

1. Je suis bien incapable de dire où ou à qui j’ai emprunté cette habitude.

Comment: J'ai la même habitude. J'imagine que l'idée est de décliner une offre sans dire explicitement "non". Mais je crois que j'accompagne souvent le "merci" de communication non verbale, soit un mouvement de tête qui esquisse un non, soit une main ouverte, paume vers l'interlocuteur et doigts vers le haut.

Answer (score 1):

*Oui, merci* n'est pas le plus employé lorsqu'on se fait servir un verre ou de la nourriture, on dit plutôt *oui, s'il te plait* ou *oui, je veux bien*. Même si *oui, merci* est utilisé, l'accent sera plutôt mis sur le *oui* pour faciliter la compréhension.

En revanche, *non merci* est clairement l'expression consacrée sans avoir besoin d'insister sur le *non*.

Par extrapolation, lorsqu'on entend *merci* tout seul sans autre signe (hochement de tête, sourire, etc.), on a plutôt tendance à en déduire que c'est un *non merci* dont on n'a pas entendu le *non*.

Donc je dirais, *merci = non merci*, par habitude et par supposition.