# Comment répondre à la question: « ça va ? » si tu es de mauvaise humeur ?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

I'm not used to this small talk stuff... and just answering "ça va" feels quite unhonest.

@jlliagre: Good question... I'm German. 1) My impression is that people in Germany
don't ask this question so often and so 'aggressive' like in France.
Which never let me think about how i would answer this question in
german 2) I can do different things: I can just answer "bad" or "I'm in
bad mood" or answer with a ironic "fantastic". I can describe what i did
recently or what i think, the way I make this description reflects my
mood. I can distract from the question, to signalize that i'm in bad
mood and don't want to talk about it. I also can use pictures to answer
the question. Of course, it depends on the context and the relation you have with person. 3) Even if the most frequently answer on the question is something like: "gut, und selbst" (good, and you) its not disturbing for the other person when you act differently. Which is the point... I have the impression this is with the frensh style of communication not easy: Frensh is much more formalized than german, they work more with expressions and pictures.

Comment: How would you answer to that question in your native language?

Comment: To me, "mauvaise humeur" means to be angry more than "in a bad mood", I would use something else for a bad mood as in "being sad". Is that what you meant ?

Comment: @Teleporting Goat: I'm hardly familiar with the nuance of French words. What I mean with bad mood or 'mauvais humeur' is something general. The opposite of good, can be sad, angry, frustrated, confused, fearful even tired.

Comment: @and The problem is it's a yes/no question, which makes it really hard to answer anything else than "yes". It's a pain even for us.

Comment: @Teleporting Goat: sry...i don't get what you want to tell me?? you mean cava is a yes/no question and its hard for French people to get a different answer then yes?

Comment: @and Well yeah, 90% of the time you'll answer "yes" even if there's something bothering you. If you want to talk about it, you have to answer "no" or "not really" and THEN explain what's wrong, and sometimes you'll have to wait for the other person to ask you "why?" to keep talking. I find it weird, it's so much easier when you're asked "*how* are you doing" and not "*Are you* doing ok?"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On pourrait dire:

> Moyen ...
>
> Bof ...
>
> Pas top ...
>
> Ca va moyen ...
>
> Ca va mal ...
>
> C'est pas la grande forme ...
>
> Y'a quelque chose qui me travaille ...
>
> Pas vraiment (, non).

Mais ces expressions sont neutres, elles veulent juste dire que ça ne va pas "très bien", mais n'impliquent pas forcément la mauvaise humeur.

Pour la mauvaise humeur, peut-être:

> Je suis grognon
>
> Je suis furax/fumasse
>
> Je suis en pétard
>
> J'suis yomb (dans la Zone)
>
> Je vois tout (en) rouge
>
> Je vais étrangler quelqu'un

On me suggère aussi, qu'en cas de mauvaise humeur, simplement ne pas répondre est ... fréquent ... et en tout cas, très *expressif* :-)

Comment: merci, ce deja pas mal :) peut être quelqu'un autre a une idee plus elegant

Comment: Je connais d'autres expressions: j'ai la haine, j'ai la rage ... mais j'hésite à les citer, car elles sont assez chargées et portent un certain contexte qui n'est pas forcément approprié.

Comment: I was also taught "Ça va mal", so I'm somewhat surprised not to see it suggested. Is it out of vogue? Too direct? Awkward?

Comment: Added. Thanks! I don't know what is in vogue these days, and it depends on where. I'm sure there are new expressions dans la Zone.

Comment: Pour ce qui est des formules "neutres" j'ajouterai "Pas vraiment", voire même "Pas vraiment, non.". Personnellement, si j'étais vraiment de mauvaise humeur, je répondrais carrément "Non" ou "Non, pas du tout." sur un ton sec/agacé. Une autre possibilité est de répondre par un grognement style *mgrl* (dur à retranscrire !) avec un air renfrogné, ça marche très bien. ;)

Comment: J'ajoute. Merci!

Answer (score 8):

Pas forcément pour signaler sa mauvaise humeur mais on pourrait dire

> Ça pourrait aller mieux.

Answer (score 3):

Je m'appuie uniquement sur *mon propre usage*, sans doute *atypique*, mais dont j'aimerais vous faire part, alors que j'ai déjà tout simplement employé :

> — Bonjour, ça va ?
>  — **Merci**, (et) vous [ça va/vous allez bien]
>   ?
>  — Oui bien, merci, mais êtes-vous certain d'avoir vraiment compris le sens de ma
>   question ?
>  — Assurément.
>  — Et... ?
>  — Et si nous allions déjeuner... ?

---

*Merci* seul par [ellipse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/12504) de *oui/non* ([Ac.9](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/merci) ; voir aussi, [Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/merci/50583?q=merci#50471)) « pouvant être une façon polie de refuser, la langue familière le fait suivre de oui ou de non quand on veut faire disparaître l'ambiguïté [...] » (LBU14 § 1108c). Mon propre usage consiste donc à la préserver et à laisser à l'interlocuteur le soin de déduire plus avant, si on n'a pas envie de spécifier du tout, directement ou par antiphrase etc., tout en lui retournant la politesse que justifie son intérêt pour nous et permettant de rapidement changer de sujet. Évidemment tout dépend de l'intention et du contexte, et il va sans dire que dans certains cas où on n'a pas l'ami(e) ou le parent inquiet et attentif à notre égard qui appuie sur la question, on ne s'attendra pas nécessairement à ce qu'on élabore sur ce qu'on ressent ni sur son état de santé lorsqu'on demande familièrement en langue parlée *comment [ça](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A7a) va* à quelqu'un... ce peut être parfois une formule de salutation ou de prise de contact ([Larousse](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/%C3%A7a/11852/locution?q=comment#177867)), donc un truc essentiellement similaire à un *bonjour* comportant (avec) une manifestation générale d'intérêt. Et ainsi la pareille en réponse, [civilité](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/civilit%C3%A9/16281?q=civilit%C3%A9#16147) demeurant.

Comment: *Merci* est une réponse très atypique. Elle risque d'être comprise comme traduisant une mauvaise compréhension de la question.

Comment: Ca ressemble à du Japonais plus qu'à du Français courant, selon moi.

Comment: @Frank Merci de préciser, il m'eût été fort difficile de deviner ça, en effet. C'est intéressant.

Comment: @のｂるしｔｙぱんｋｙ- précision: je parle Japonais, et je fais référence à une pratique de communication qui existe en Japonais, où la politesse peut passer avant une description précise de l'état de la personne. On trouve en Japonais également la possibilité de répondre _excusez-moi_ pour _merci_ dans certains cas. Je pense donc à ce genre de choses en écho de la remarque de jlliagre...

Comment: @jlliagre Je réponds souvent _merci_ à ce genre de questions que je sois en bonne humeur ou non, juste pour éviter le _ça va_ traditionnel. :) Jusqu'à là, personne ne m'a posé de questions supplémentaires.

Comment: @Oreste ***Bien**, merci* est plus attendu. En disant seulement *merci*, on n'a pas répondu à la question posée, ce qui peux étonner mais n'entraînera pas de question supplémentaire, c'est vrai.

Comment: @jlliagre _En disant seulement "merci", on n'a pas répondu à la question posée_ C'est vrai, mais cela n'a guère d'importance. De toute façon, on répond habituellement _ça va (, merci)_ Je ne fais qu'abréger. :)

Comment: @Oreste Si si, ça a de l'importance. En fait, ça pourrait même être mal pris de ne pas répondre à une question posée et d'enchaîner sur une autre, même si le *merci* atténue le problème. Contrairement à l'anglais où on répond à peu près toujours quelque chose comme *I'm fine. Thank you. What about you ?* à *How are you doing?* en France, on se sent moins obligé de dire que ça va bien quand ce n'est pas le cas. La personne qui a posé la question s'attend à une réponse. Imagine : *Tu es venue en taxi ? Merci, et toi ?*

Comment: @jlliagre Ah oui ? Intéressant. :) Si jamais je viens en France un jour, je m'en souviendrai. J'aimerais en fait, sur les images, le pays est si beau. Puis, il y a des Français qui m'ont beaucoup aidée. // Mais peut-être qu'au Québec c'est différent ? En tout cas, personne n'a pas été vexé à cause de mon merci tout seul, je le dis dans toutes les langues que je parle. Mais j'ajoute aussi un sourire, d'habitude. // Mais attends, je me souviens, mon vét, je lui ai demandé _Ça va ?_, je ne m'attendais même pas à une réponse, j'étais surtout concentrée sur mon lapin,

Comment: je l'ai dit au lieu de _bonjour_. Et il m'a répondu _merci_, sans répondre à ma question -- puisque de toute façon, je voulais surtout parler de mon lapin --, et sans me relancer ce _Ça va ?_, qui, j'avoue, me lasse parfois. // _La personne qui a posé la question s'attend à une réponse_ Oui ?... Un jour, j'ai fait une expérience, j'ai répondu _pas bien_, la moitié des personnes ne l'ont pas entendu. :) // _Imagine : Tu es venue en taxi ?_ Mais ce n'est pas pareil. _Ça va ?_ est devenu une formule passe-partout.

Comment: @jlliagre J'ai déjà entendu cet usage. La non-réponse n'est un problème que quand la question a vraiment pour objectif de receuillir une information, dans le cas du "ça va?" on est clairement dans une utilisation phatique de l'expression. Le vrai sens de "ça va?" c'est souvent "je note que nous sommes en train de démarrer une intéraction sociale. Si tu veux lancer un sujet de discussion sur ta vie, c'est le bon moment car je suis disponible à écouter.". Dans ce cas une réponse comme "merci et vous?" signifie "je ne veux pas parler de moi, mais si, toi, tu veux parler de toi, vas-y."

Answer (score 1):

Classiquement, même si on ne va pas très bien, on répondra quand même

> ça va

avec une moue signifiant que ce n'est pas la grande forme. La personne suivant si elle a l'envie/le temps de vous parler plus vous dira :

> c'est pas la grande forme!

ou

> ça, c'est un petit "ça va"!

> Tu es sûr que ça va ?

Il y a d'autres possibilités, pour éviter de répondre toujours "ça va", pour varier, éventuellement signifier que tout ne va pas parfaitement bien, sans dramatiser, voire de façon un peu humoristique :

> - Comme un lundi [note : ou le jour concerné]
> - On fait aller !